# How do I create a header with JQuery that is fixed on top on scroll up but hides on scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a site product where I have to create a site-header that is always fixed on top of the viewport but when I scroll down it hides, and again when I scroll up, it becomes visible again. Actually, I made it happen somehow but I think the JQuery I used can be simpler and currently have some unnecessary variations in it. I used the JQuery from a reference available on internet.

Here is my code.

HTML

```
    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
    .site-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: transform .25s;}

    .hidden {transform:translateY(-100%)}
```

JQuery

```
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
        var didScroll;
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var delta = 5;
        var navbarHeight = $('.site-header').outerHeight();

        $(window).scroll(function(event){
            didScroll = true;
        });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If scrolled down and past the site-header, add class .hidden.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.site-header').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.site-header').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
    }
    } );
```

Now, all these things together are functional and I have a header that is fixed, but when I scroll down, it disappears and when I scroll back up, it becomes visible again- as I wanted. But, since I am not much familiar with JQuery at all, I am not sure if this JQuery can be more simpler. Because, I think it would be great if I can achieve the same results with a smaller and simpler JQuery.

I made this work but I believe a smaller and simpler JQuery can make this same function work too.

Answer (score 0):

This solution shows a fixed header that fades out and in on scroll. A `conf.hideFactor` threshold determines at what scroll pos the header fades out, `0.5` is half the header height. The trick is to hide/show only when needed, done with a `.is(':visible')` check

```js
const conf = {
  hideFactor: 0.5   // factor of site-header height to hide
};
$('document').ready(function() {
  const $headerElem = $('.site-header');
  let navbarHeight = $headerElem.outerHeight();
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    let scrollPos = Math.round($(document).scrollTop());
    let headerIsVisible = $headerElem.is(':visible');
    if(scrollPos > navbarHeight * conf.hideFactor) {
      if(headerIsVisible) {
        console.log('Hide at ' + scrollPos);
        $headerElem.hide('slow');
      }
    } else if(!headerIsVisible) {
      console.log('Show at ' + scrollPos);
      $headerElem.show('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.main-content {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 65px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="inner">
  This header is fixed and fades away on scroll
  </div>
</header>
<div class="main-content">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<p>Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </p>
<p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. </p>
<p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really don't want to change how my JQuery works, I just want if there is a simpler code to achieve the same result. Hide fixed header on scroll down and show it back again on scroll up. That's it.

Comment: Are you concenred about the code not looking the same or the behavior not the same? If you don;t like the animation, change `.show('slow')` to `.show()`. If you want to hide as soon as scroll begins, set `conf.hideFactor` to 1, or remove it all together.

Comment: If you are looking for code review, use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Peter, I made the necessary changes. Works fine now.

Comment: Got my answer on codereview.stackexchange as suggested.

Comment: Specifically, Chotu's code was reviewed as [JQuery fixed header that hides on scroll down and shows on scroll up](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/282431/75307), in case anyone here wants to see the outcome.